How to add a north arrow using stock QGIS images in Python
I am trying to add a north arrow to a map (QgsPrintLayout) using PyQGIS. The closest thing I could find is from this GIS.SE question (Adding north arrow using PyQGIS):
north = QgsLayoutItemPicture(layout)
north.setPicturePath("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/logo.svg")
layout.addLayoutItem(north)
north.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(23, 23,gsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
north.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(3,234,QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

From the line north.setPicturePath("C:/Users/Pc/Desktop/logo.svg") , it seems that there is no specific layout item for north arrows, and north arrows are treated as pictures. (Or is there a special QgsLayoutItem for north arrows?)
But I don't really have decent images (such as the loco.svg) for north arrows on every computer (or want to maintain them).
Are there stock image(s) for north arrows that I could use from standard QGIS installations? (those used internally in the QGIS desktop program)
And where are the north arrow images located, or how can they be accessed in python?
(This is with QGIS 3.34 under Ubuntu 24.04 LTS).

not sure where they are on an Ubuntu Installation but if you open a composer and add an image, you can look in the 'arrows' folder in SVG Groups and should be able to see the location of where they're saved.
